# Effeciently match optional characters that must be insequence

Tags: regex

Well, I got it working, but somehow it looks slow and inefficient (or maybe not).

What I've got is a sequence of characters, for simplicity sake let's just say it's

```
123456789
```

What I want to do is to make sure the input begins the same way, and  is in the same sequence, but doesn't need to be the complete sequence.

What I've got is this:

```
^1(2(3(4(5(6(7(8(9)?)?)?)?)?)?)?)?
```

This looks pretty horrid, but is there a better way to do this?

**Edit** Added the `^` that was in the original code and I forgot to include here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A ? quantifier is is like a spare part. Think of the engine that runs fine without it. It will try to ingore it if possible.

Sure x?x?x?x?x? looks pretty bad. But, its almost meaningless unless used with some context around it.

Asuming your groupings are just to denote options, you could factor out the last inner-group using this `1(2(3(4(5(6(7(89?)?)?)?)?)?)?)?`.

Example:

`1(2(3(4(5(6(7(8(9)?)?)?)?)?)?)?)?` will globally match this

987654321 1111111111111112121211112121121212312111 multiple times.

So, its all relative.

Comment: Whoops, I forgot to add the `^` at the beginning of the regex I used in the original question to make sure it matches from the start of the string.

So I assume having so many nested `(()?)?` is ok in this context?

Comment: That should be ok. Remember that () is a capture buffer, while (?:) is for clustering sub-expressions. Some engines might have a limit on the amount of capture buffers available. I looked at Perl and saw no reference to a limit on nested groupings. I think the level is related to the stack. Perl does have a compiled limit on recursion levels. Think its about 50. This may be related but I'm not sure.